# Java left shift clarification

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am unable to figure out the reason for this behavior. I want to left shift by 8 bits the byte value `OxAB`. Then I want to convert that to a long.

```
byte oneByte = (byte) 0xAB;
long converted = (oneByte & 0xFF) << 8;
System.out.println(converted);
```

In this case the output is `43776`. However, if I change the code to this:

```
byte oneByte = (byte) 0xAB;
long converted = (oneByte) << 8;
System.out.println(converted);
```

The output changes to -21760. I have following questions:

1. What is the data type of `0xFF`?
2. Why is bitwise AND with `0xFF` preventing sign extension?

Comment: Sign extension on a left shift? There’s no sign to extend that direction.

Comment: @DaveNewton the bit pattern of 0xAB is 1010 1011. I think when Java promotes a byte to a long it is using that leftmost 1 as a sign bit. I don't have a clear understanding of this behavior.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean--I guess I've never really considered that "sign extension", but I suppose it is.

Comment: @sshekhar That is correct. Bytes are signed in Java, so it is a sign bit, so it gets extended, not by the shift but at the point it is widened to `int` before the shift. Your `(oneByte & 0xFF)` expression gets truncated to 8 bits by the mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
long converted = onebyte; // gives you -85
```

and if you shift it 8 times to the left it gives you exactly -21760
because during the conversion to long the left most bit is used as a sign bit.

```
long converted = onebyte & 0xFF; //gives you 171
```

and if you shift it 8 times to the left it gives you 43776

because when using the bitwise and byte, short and char are converted to an int first and then the bitwise operation is executed.

```
11111111111111111111111110101011 //byte 0xAB casted to int
00000000000000000000000011111111 //0xFF is an int literal
00000000000000000000000010101011 //bitwise and operation
```

after the bitwise and with 0xFF the sign bit is removed

Comment: But you didn't say why.

Comment: @pero_hero so you are saying 0xFF is an INT literal and that is why 24 bits are zero. But in case of 0xAB, which is a byte literal, when it is promoted to INT the sign bit is extended. I think that makes sense. Thanks a bunch!